# Alert to display distance between elements

Tags: jquery, position

I have a wrapper. Inside that wrapper I have an inner-wrapper. Inside that inner-wrapper I have a span. On that span mouseenter, I would like an alert to show the distance between the middle of that span and the right border of the wrapper (the main one: #wrapper). I tried few things with position() but did not manage to achieve what I just mentioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP7Lt/

My html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
        <span id="me">It's me</span>
    </div>
</div>​
```

My css:

```
#wrapper{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    background-color:yellow;}

#inner-wrapper{
    position:absolute;            
    width:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color:blue;}

#me{
    background-color:pink;}
```

​
My js:

```
$('#me').mouseenter(function(){


    alert("distance from middle of span till right border of #wrapper???");

})​
```

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles, and/or signatures in posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#me').mouseenter(function(){
    var $wrapper = $("#wrapper"), $this = $(this);
    alert("distance from middle of span till right border of #wrapper is " + ($wrapper.width() - ($this.offset().left - $wrapper.offset().left + $this.width()/2)));
})​;
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/NxhWk/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it helps

```
var spanLeft = $("#me").offset().left;
var wrapper = $("#wrapper").offset().left;                 
alert("distance from middle of span till right border of #wrapper???");
alert(spanLeft - wrapper);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a combination of [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
$('#me').mouseenter(function(){
    var middle = $(this).offset().left + $(this).width()/2;
    var wrapperRight = $("#wrapper").offset().left+$("#wrapper").width();

    alert( wrapperRight - middle);

})​
```

**EDIT:**
Fixed a the math error

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmvqr/6/)

Comment: Hello JJS. thanks for trying to help. Neverthless according to the result something is wrong. The distance displayed is greater than the one of the main wrapper width. Thnks anyway...

Comment: How about this? `code`$(this).parent('div').outerWidth() - ($(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth() / 2)

Comment: Sorry about that Marc.  The error was my parentheses around "$(this).offset().left + $(this).width()".  not sure what I was thinking.